# Input data in .dat file

Tags: cplex, opl

I am solving a multi period problem. There are 6 customers and 3 periods. The demands of customer are written as following in excel:

```
Customer 1 Demand in period 1(B3)  Demand of period 2  Demand in period 3(D3)

Customer 6
```

I have written as following in .dat:  `Dem from SheetRead(sheet,"Data!B3:D8");`
It is giving an error

Comment: Please list the error.

Comment: You may find a SheetRead example in CPLEX_Studio128\opl\examples\opl\oil

Comment: Got the file ... but the problem is not solved

Answer (score -1):

.mod

```
range customers=1..6;
range periods=1..3;

int Dem[customers][periods]=...;
```

.dat

```
SheetConnection sheet("test.xlsx");

Dem from SheetRead(sheet,"Data!B3:D8");
```

Works fine.

Are you sure you have excel and you have a Windows machine ?